# How can I pass a null reference in matlab so that isa returns true?

Tags: matlab, reference, null

I have a class `Foo` and a function that gets `Foo` as input parameter. In this function I also do some error checking using `isa`:

```
function (x)  
  if ~isa(x,'Foo')  
     error('Wrong!');  
  end
```

I want to pass it something that is like null in Java. However when I pass it `[]` I get an error.  Can you tell me what can I do? I though about always passing a cell array or checking for `empty` everytime I use `isa`.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you can check our condition with

```
  validParam = isa(x,'Foo') || isempty(x);
```

However, the best way will be to create an empty class using the static method `empty`:

```
  e = Foo.empty(0);
  isa(x,'Foo')
```

And the result is:

> isa(Foo.empty(0),'Foo')
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 1
> ```

By the way, this is also useful for another case - Suppose you want to grow dynamically and array of `Foo` objects. You could use a cell array, but then you lose the type safety. Instead, create `Foo.empty()` .

Nevertheless, there is a caveeat in using this method. It is not smart enough to handle inheritance -

Let `Bar` be a class that inherits from `Foo`.

```
classdef Bar < Foo

end
```

And you allocate a new array of `Foo` objects:

```
x = Foo.empty(0)
```

> x =
>
> 0x0 empty Foo with no properties.
>    Methods

Then try to add `Bar` :

```
x(end+1) = Bar()
```

> ??? The following error occurred converting from Bar to Foo:
>   Error using ==> Foo
>   Too many input arguments.

So the only workaround for this case is to use cell array.

---

**Edit(1):**  It seems that Matlab have added a [special class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneous-class.html) in order to handle inheritance:

> Description
>
> matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous is an abstract class that provides support
>   for the formation of heterogeneous arrays. A heterogeneous array is an
>   array of objects that differ in their specific class, but are all
>   derived from or are instances of a root class. The root class derives
>   directly from matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous.